# How to combine two mvc dropdown lists with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

As I am relativly new to mvc and our software developer is not around today so I need to ask for help on this way. I have to dropdown lists and dropdown 2 needs to be filled depending on the selection on dropdown 1.

```
@(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User.NrLand, Model.CountriesList, "--Select--", new { id="myCountry" }))
```

This results in a dropdown list like:

```
<select>
   <option value="10">Australia</option>
   <option value="20">India</option>
   <option value="30">USA</option>
</select>
```

Now I have a second dropdown list that needs a param to be filled dynamically depending on the results of dropdown 1. Where the xxxxx is just a placeholder at the moment, I have to include the selected value (as int) from dropdown 1.

```
@(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User.NrState, Model.StatesList(xxxxx), "--Select--", new { id="myState" })
```

should be

```
@(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User.NrState, Model.StatesList(20), "--Select--", new { id="myState" }))
```

for example. But how can this be one on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as dropdown cascading. refer this [Dropdown cascading](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/cascading-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) similar to you requirement.

Comment: ah, so I have to make additional changes to the controller? :-/  I've feared that answer :-D  Thank you, I'll see what I can do!